# longestCommonPrefix returned from function but not printed to console in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

In the code below, the function returns a char pointer "p" and is stored in the "out" variable which is also a pointer. When I try to print using printf statement, it does not output anything to console, Any pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * longestCommonPrefix(char **strs, int strsSize){
    int j = 0;
    char *p;
    char result[10];
    int len = strlen(result);
    while(j < strlen(strs[0])){
        if(strs[0][j] == strs[1][j] && strs[1][j] == strs[2][j]){
            result[len++] = strs[0][j];
        }
        j++;
    }
    result[len] = '\0';
    p = result;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    char *arr[] = {"flower", "flow", "flight"};
    char **ptr; 
    char *out;
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    ptr = arr;
    out = longestCommonPrefix(ptr, size);//breakpoint here shows the expected output
    printf("%s", out); //does not print the output to console
}
```

Comment: `p` and `result` are local variables of `longestCommonPrefix`. They do not exist anymore after the function returns.

Comment: One solution is to "return a pointer to one of the input strings and an integer length. In standard C you can only return one thing, but you can have a pointer argument that you could modify for the other one. One ugly solution would be to instead return the index to one of the strings and the length, and then store those as upper and lower values in a single returned integer, but this restricts the size of the array or strings you can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Paul Ogilvie, I was able to solve it by dynamic memory allocation in heap, strcpy to the pointer and returning the pointer as the local memory was not existing by the time, I was printing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * longestCommonPrefix(char **strs, int strsSize){
    int j = 0;
    char* p = malloc(10 * sizeof *p);
    char result[10];
    int len = strlen(result);
    while(j < strlen(strs[0])){
        if(strs[0][j] == strs[1][j] && strs[1][j] == strs[2][j]){
            result[len++] = strs[0][j];
        }
        j++;
    }
    result[len] = '\0';
    strcpy(p, result);
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    char *arr[] = {"flower", "flow", "flight"};
    char **ptr;
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    ptr = arr;
    char *out = longestCommonPrefix(ptr, size);
    printf("%s\n", out);
    free(out);
}
```

Comment: Change the line where you call `malloc` to `char* p = malloc(10 * sizeof *p);`